# Can Roambi or any iPad app make authorized http-requests to pull data to visualize?

Tags: ipad

Can [Roambi](http://www.roambi.com/features.html) or any iPad app make authorized http-requests to pull data (say JSON or .csv) from some source and interactively visualize it on the iPad screen?

Comment: That Roambi looks neat. Do you have links to other similar apps?

Comment: @Thilo I am still searching for other apps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Roambi (but it does seem like they care about the security of their clients' business data, so the requests from the app are very likely authenticated and encrypted), but of course an iPad app can make HTTP requests that include authentication information, if that was your question. Even Mobile Safari supports Basic Auth, for example.